# Extract value from JSON based on another value

Tags: json, grep, jq

I have a result as shown below in json format. I parsed the respective text file using jq.

`cat file.txt | jq`

Results

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "input": {
        "FUZZ": "fuzzerhere"
      },
      "position": 53,
      "status": 403,
      "length": 670,
      "words": 105,
      "lines": 9,
      "redirectlocation": "",
      "resultfile": "",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/fuzzerhere",
      "host": "www.example.com"
    },
    {
      "input": {
        "FUZZ": "newfuzz"
      },
      "position": 53,
      "status": 200,
      "length": 670,
      "words": 105,
      "lines": 9,
      "redirectlocation": "",
      "resultfile": "",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/newfuzz",
      "host": "www.example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Requirement: I want to grep or extract from the output satisfying a condition. 
Condition: status == 200 
Output: The respective output should contain all urls which has a status 200, considering the below example, the output has to be
`https://www.example.com/newfuzz`

I tried using grep
`cat file.txt | jq | grep '"status": 403'`

The above command gave me the line status only , then I realised extracting from an array of objects in json is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all with jq:

```sh
jq -r '.results[] | select(.status == 200).url'
```

returns the `url` field for all array element where `status` is `200`.